# Play html5 video with buffering on apache with php

Tags: php, html, apache, video, buffering

I have a simple a html5 video tag pointing to a mp4 video through php.
My problem is that the **video starts playing only after it has been completely loaded by the browser**.

How should I output video with php? I have used http ranges headers but nothing.

How should I configure apache so that can start playing the video at once (once it has downloaded only a part) ? is there any module should I enable?

html code:

```
<video width="640" height="264" preload="none" controls="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" id="approval-playing-video"> 
   <source type="video/mp4" src="dam/index/get-video-preview?id=186&amp;md5=3386d3701e403c69e1c4323168f6ee74"></source> 
</video>
```

Php (ZF2 framework) server code:

```
    $response = new Stream();
    $response->setStream(fopen($file, 'r'));
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->setStreamName(basename($file));

    $headers = new Headers();
    $headers->addHeaders(array(
        'Content-Type'      => 'video/mp4',
        'Accept-Ranges'     => 'bytes',
        'Content-Length'    => filesize($file)
    ));

    return $response->setHeaders($headers)->setContent($file);
```

System test:
Centos, Apache 2, PHP 5.4
Test with Firefox 24

Any suggestion will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make sure your server can play a video properly formatted for "fast start":

You can download the file at http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4 and host it on your server. If it works fine (ie video starts before full download) then your server/script config is ok.

If the above works the issue is probably that your mp4 is not properly formatted. You can try to use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) or [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) to repack your file. You need to activate the "web optimized" option (aka fast start) with handbrake.

For MP4Box (linux): `MP4Box -inter 500 yourFile.mp4`

More info on this [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html).

Comment: Thank you. How should I check server can play a video properly formatted for "fast start"?

Comment: Download http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4 and host it on your server. Try to play it and see if it starts immediately.

Comment: Yes, actually the sample is working, so the problem is the video.